# Why was "yarn install X" renamed to "yarn add X"?

Tags: yarnpkg

When I run `yarn install SOME_PACKAGE_X` it says:

```
error `install` has been replaced with `add` to add new dependencies. Run "yarn add fourtytwo" instead.
```

Other package managers use `install` as a      keyword to *install* a package. For example npm, Debian's apt and so on. Even the [classic docs](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/) for yarn 1.x `add`  talked     about installing packages instead of adding them.

I see that [`yarn install`](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/install) serves the purpose to install all dependencies. From what I see, it would have been better to rename the "install all" command instead.
In the current way, I see only drawbacks: The naming seems inconsistent. I cannot alias npm to yarn, although they share most other commands.

This confuses me. When I read about yarn in the past, it was stated, they often  do things differently, but do so for a reason.

Could someone explain the rationale in this case?